# React Native App - add buttons that trigger specific screen function on both header and tab navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app using React-Native and I'm stuck with the following problem: I need to create a screen with custom Header and Bottom Tabs (Header should have 2 buttons: Go back and Review) and bottom tabs should have 2 buttons as well ( Import and Proceed ).

I've tried the following approach for the header as seen below, but I get an error (undefined is not an object) whenever I click on any of the 2 buttons. Also, I don't know if I pass props correctly in the Review screen (I need to pass props of New.js Screen, and the piece of code below is in App.js)

```
 <Stack.Screen name="New" component={New} navigation={this.props.navigation}
        options={{
            headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate('Review', { name: name, data: data })}
              title="Review"
              
            />
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => this.navigation.goBack()}
              title="Back"
              
            />
          ),
        }}
        />
```

And the for the bottom tabs, I couldn't find a way to make it work for my scenario. I tried making this work with an Empty component because that way, it will not pass the overall app bottom tabs, because I need a specific one here (with 2 buttons only)

```
const EmptyContainer = () => {
return(null)
};

//.....

<Tab.Screen name="NewContainer" component={EmptyContainer} 
            listeners={({navigation}) => ({
                tabPress: event => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    navigation.navigate('New');
                }
            })}
            options ={{
                tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-box" color ={color} size={12}/>
                )
            }}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

### No.1

You don't have to pass navigation object as props.

Stack option can receive it as one of the arguments. Plase look at the example code below.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="New"
    component={New}
    options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Review', { name: name, data: data })}
          title="Review"
        />
    })}
/>
```

### No.2

As for the back button, `React Navigation` has a awesome API to change only the appearance of it.

You can find some solution to change the title or the icon of the original back button like the link below.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/header-buttons#customizing-the-back-button

Comment: Thanks! That helped me! But now I get an error with the props of navigation. It doesn't recognize them. Do I have to add anything else on my New.js so that stack screen will know to take props from that page and move them further?

Comment: More specific: the props in the navigation.navigate(review....) -> the name, and data, are states in New.js screen that I want to pass further

Comment: I guess that is a different problem.  Is your `<Stack.screen name="New" />` and `<Stack.screen name="Review" />` are in the same Stack.Navigator?

Comment: I think you can open a new question about the new error, so that we can see the code more precisely and you will get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the back button is default on react navigation. So it's not necessary to set the header left option.

Ensure that if you like to use the "navigation" prop you're inside a navigation container. Otherwise it won't recognise the navigation feature because it's an core function of react navigation.

Therefore you can use the concept of [nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/).

Here's an example:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const reviewData = "foo"

function MainStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={ImportScreen} options={{
          headerRight: () => (
          <Pressable onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Review', {data: reviewData})}}>
              <Text>Review</Text>
          </Pressable>
        ),}} />
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="Review" component={ReviewScreen} />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() { 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator.Navigator>
        <TabNavigator.Screen name="Import" component={MainStack} />
        <TabNavigator.Screen name="Proceed" component={YourOtherScreen} />
      </TabNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The props I want to pass are not like this. The StackNavigator is in App.js, but what I want, is to pass New.js to Review.js props, as name and data. Any idea on how to get that working?